# IntelliJ Swing Designer and adding forms at runtime to another Component

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is shipped with the cool Swing designer that allows one to build UIs very quickly.

When you start by creating a dialog or a form, IntelliJ creates project files to keep info about the Swing components to be rendered.

For instance, when I start to create a form, it creates a Java class that is bound to a `.form` file.

[image]

Everything clear here, but I wonder if I can somehow instantiate several instances of this component inside another at runtime.

E.g. the `MyForm` in my picture is maybe created at runtime using a for-each inside another `JPanel`, and therefore I expect to have a [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) in order to call `add` on the `JPanel`. However the IntelliJ class is not a component.

So, is IntelliJ GUI designer meant to be used only for static GUIs and therefore I must design all the templates by myself, or can I somehow reuse the UI designed using the designer?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "dynamic" parts. You can insatiate gui forms yourself. You can also bind the designer .form to the existing class. Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer-basics.html

Comment: @Andrey please, can you show an example of a form instantiated  via Java and added to a component (e.g. a JFrame or a JPanel)?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Gridlayoutmanager` at user interface. I used `GridBaglayout` and solved the problem. You can add components at run time using `gridbaglayout` at intellij.

Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206879815